# Elide Text in Middle for QLabel C++

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

Hi I am interested in eliding text in a QLabel in the middle of the text in C++. I found the [text elide mode property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#TextElideMode-enum) but it looks it only applies to QAbstractItemViews. Also [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-elidedlabel-example.html) it says **QLabel can elide text that doesn't fit within it, but only in one line** but then doesn't say how to do it. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701424/how-to-use-text-elidemiddle-in-a-label) it is super easy but it's in QML/Qt Quick. Is there an easy way to do this? Do I have to override the paint event and use QFontMetrics or something like that? I'd imagine this would be as simple as setting a text elide middle property but perhaps I am mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: From the [Elided Label Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-elidedlabel-example.html) (your link): `QString lastLine = content.mid(line.textStart());
QString elidedLastLine = fontMetrics.elidedText(lastLine, Qt::ElideRight, width());
painter.drawText(QPoint(0, y + fontMetrics.ascent()), elidedLastLine);`

Comment: [QFontMetrics::elidedText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText) is used to convert the original string into a new one where parts might be replaced by the ellipses. There you can provide the `Qt::TextElideMode`. However, it seems that `QLabel` doesn't support ellipses out of the box. - You have to make your custom label like shown in the linked sample.

Comment: There is nothing native for QLabel yet. This feature has been requested for many years, see [QTBUG-4250](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-4250).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code thanks to Scheff's Cat.

```
//elidedlabel.h
#ifndef ELIDEDLABEL_H
#define ELIDEDLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>

class ElidedLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ElidedLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void setText(const QString &text);
    const QString & text() const { return content; }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    QString content;
};

#endif // ELIDEDLABEL_H


//elidedlabel.cpp
#include "elidedlabel.h"

ElidedLabel::ElidedLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
}

void ElidedLabel::setText(const QString &newText)
{
    content = newText;
    update();
}

void ElidedLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    QFontMetrics fontMetrics = painter.fontMetrics();

    QString elidedLine = fontMetrics.elidedText(content, Qt::ElideMiddle, width());
    painter.drawText(QPoint(0, fontMetrics.ascent()), elidedLine);
}
```